# Error when creating Amazon AWS android project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

The error information as follows:

Unable to copy AWS SDK for Android jar to project's lib directory
Could not uniquely identify an SDK jar inC:\Users\93689-0\aws-android-sdk\2.1.10\lib.  Found: [Ljava.io.File;@53717d85

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Find the source from the github. 
aws-toolkit-eclipse/com.amazonaws.eclipse.android.sdk
/src/com/amazonaws/eclipse/android/sdk/AndroidSdkInstall.java

public File getSdkJar() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File[] files = libDirectory.listFiles(new  AndroidSdkLibraryJarFilenameFilter());
        if (files == null || files.length != 1) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    **"***Could not uniquely identify an SDK jar in"
                            + this.libDirectory + ".  Found: " + files***);**
        }
        return files[0];
    }